# Why mysql data print only last row inside email body?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am getting an email with header and the last row. why not all rows?

Here is my full code:

```
$email_from = 'info@email.com';
    $email_to = $row['email'];
    $email_subject = "The " . $row['event'] . " Registration";

    $email_message .= "Dear " . $row['lname'] . " " . $row['fname'] . "\n" ;
    $email_message .= "This is a notice that an invoice for your order has been generated on " . $row['reg_date'] . "\n" ;
    $email_message .= "Your payment method is: " . $row['payment'] . "\n" ;
    $email_message .= "Invoice: " . $row['id'] . "\n" ;
    $email_message .= "Status: Unpaid \n" ;
    $email_message .= "<strong>Invoice Items</strong> \n" ;
    $email_message .= "Event: " . $row['event'] . "\n" ;
    $email_message .= "<hr> \n" ;
    $email_message .= "<hr> \n" ;
    $email_message .= "Here is your Invoice id: ".$row['ref']. "\n" ;

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

I want to Email like this

```
Dear Dasgupta Arnab
This is a notice that an invoice for your order has been generated on: date
Your payment method is: whatever
Invoice: 123456
Status: Unpaid 
Invoice Items 
Event: event name
Here is your Invoice: refid
```

but I'm getting only like this in email

```
Here is your Invoice: refid
```

Comment: are you saying only `$email_message .= "Here is your Invoice id: ".$row['ref']. "\n" ;` is in the message body?

Comment: do you mean that I have to name different for each row??

Comment: @ArnabDasguptaADG I did not understand at first. No you do not have to give every line separately.

Comment: Is this code part of a loop that processes each row in the query result?

Comment: Are you using `mysqli` or `PDO`? You have both tags.

Comment: im still  trying to understand the question, if $row is a multi dimensional array then you need to loop it,

Comment: Please, post the raw email that you're getting in the email client, so we can understand your problem better!

Comment: @ÖzgürCanKaragöz I tried with one. It's not working.

Comment: @Barmar This code is working with normal contact form. When we start with "if isset "

And I am using PDO.

Comment: @GuilhermeLemmi updated.

Comment: The only explanation I can see for your result is that the last `$email_message` assignment uses `=` instead of `.=`. Check the code carefullly.

Comment: If you're putting HTML `<hr>` in the message, you need a `Content-type: text/html` header and you should use `<br>` for line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
    $email_from = 'info@email.com';
$email_to = $row['email'];
$email_subject = "The " . $row['event'] . " Registration";
$email_message="";
$email_message .= "Dear " . $row['lname'] . " " . $row['fname'] . "\n" ;
$email_message .= "This is a notice that an invoice for your order has been generated on " . $row['reg_date'] . "\n" ;
$email_message .= "Your payment method is: " . $row['payment'] . "\n" ;
$email_message .= "Invoice: " . $row['id'] . "\n" ;
$email_message .= "Status: Unpaid \n" ;
$email_message .= "<strong>Invoice Items</strong> \n" ;
$email_message .= "Event: " . $row['event'] . "\n" ;
$email_message .= "<hr> \n" ;
$email_message .= "<hr> \n" ;
$email_message .= "Here is your Invoice id: ".$row['ref']. "\n" ;
// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

Comment: Don't just post code, explain what the problem is and how your code fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code:

```
$row = ['email' => 'test@test.com', 'lname' => 'Testname', 'payment' => 'Invoice', 'id' => '1', 'event' => 'sold', 'ref' => '111222333'];

$email_from = 'info@email.com';
$email_to = $row['email'];
$email_subject = 'The ' . $row['event'] . ' Registration';

$email_message = '';
$email_message .= 'Dear ' . $row['lname'] . ' ' . $row['fname'] . "\n";
$email_message .= 'This is a notice that an invoice for your order has been generated on ' . $row['reg_date'] . "\n";
$email_message .= 'Your payment method is: ' . $row['payment'] . "\n";
$email_message .= 'Invoice: ' . $row['id'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "Status: Unpaid\n";
$email_message .= "<strong>Invoice Items</strong>\n";
$email_message .= 'Event: ' . $row['event'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "<hr>\n";
$email_message .= "<hr>\n";
$email_message .= 'Here is your Invoice id: ' . $row['ref'] . "\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: ' . $email_from . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $email_from . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

And generated email message in raw like this:

```
Received: from spooler by 127.0.0.1 (Mercury/32 v4.62); 30 May 2018 08:51:35 +0200
Received: from L-PC.DOMAIN.LOCAL (127.0.0.1) by 127.0.0.1 (Mercury/32 v4.62) ID MG000001;
   30 May 2018 08:51:33 +0200
Date: Wed, 30 May 2018 08:51:33 +0200
Subject: The sold Registration
To: test@test.com
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:index.php
From: info@email.com
Reply-To: info@email.com
X-Mailer: PHP/7.2.3
Message-ID: <3DE5C9E94CE0@127.0.0.1>

Dear Testname 
This is a notice that an invoice for your order has been generated on 
Your payment method is: Invoice
Invoice: 1
Status: Unpaid
<strong>Invoice Items</strong>
Event: sold
<hr>
<hr>
Here is your Invoice id: 111222333
```

If it does not work on your site than there is some another problem.

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what's wrong in the original code and how your version fixes it.

Comment: Questiner can take his code and new code, and compare it with Total Commander for example and he will see and analyze what he did wrong. Many codes here are small bugs which doesnt need any special explain.

Comment: This site isn't just for the questioner, it's a resource for thousands of users. They shouldn't all have to run a comparison program to see what you did.

Comment: The only difference I can see is that you added `$email_message = '';` at the beginning. How would that solve the problem he's having?